# "When to declare and handle the exception".

Tags: java

This is a very common question but i did not get satisfactory answer. To be precise, under which conditions should we declare the exceptions(using throws) and handle (try catch) in other conditions. Please suggests !

Comment: throw it when it should be thrown and catch it where you can really handle it

Comment: I'm sure there are satisfactory answers all around the internet. Or all around this site alone... Please read the [FAQ] (And @PhilippSander has the definitive answer here.)

Comment: Philipp, 
We can throw any exception from a method, so why we need a try catch, or vice versa. we can handle any checked  exception, then why we need to throw it.
If you have any example, that would be  great !

Answer (score 0):

see what happens if you dont keep thorws with a method
the other developer who is calling the method might not notice that this method will throw this exception
now if he tests the method with a different set of input
then there is a possibility that the other developer will not throw that exception
but when the program is ready , the user might again fill the input to throw the exception
so as a developer what you should do is , keep the throws keyword in method definition so the other developer knows that he has to handle or forward this sort of exception